# write a method that finds the most frequent value in 1d array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have tried some methods in python using Counter and Union, but I got no solution.

When I run the code, I get `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'numpy. ndarray' and 'int'` errors.

I have tried

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Union
from collections import Counter

def most_frequent_val(array:np.ndarray) -> Union[int,float,str]:
  counts = Counter()
  counts.most_common(array)
```

My input is an array

```
inps =np.array(["a","b","c","d","a","a","b","c","e","e","a"])
```

I have used `print(np.bincount(x).argmax())` too but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about trying this

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(0, 10, 40)
print("Original array:")
print(x)
print("Most frequent value in the above array:")
print(np.bincount(x).argmax())
```

Comment: When I implemented I got "TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<U1') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'" error.